# how to call __post_init__ in both subclass and baseclass which are defined by @dataclass

Tags: derived-class, python-dataclasses, method-resolution-order

```
@dataclass
class A:
    a: int = 0

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.a = 1


@dataclass
class C(A):
    c: int = 0

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.c = 1
```

```
>>>print(C())

C(a=0, c=1)
```

I have two classes defined as above, and C is derived from A.
When I called c=C(), the baseclass's '**post_init**' is called only, but the subclass's not.

So what is the reason of that? And if I want both **post_init** to be called, how could I do?

Comment: The solution is to add a `super().__post_init__()` within C.__post_init__(). Looks like this has the desired result of `C(a=1, c=1)`.

Comment: @rv.kvetch That gives me the solution. Thanks a lot~